# Do I need to pull up the inhibit pin on the TLE7469?

Tags: integrated-circuit

I'm looking to use the TLE7469 to provide my board 3.3V and 5V. I'll be powering it with 24V. My specific question is about the Inhibit functionality of this part. It says that it has an "integrated pull-down resistor". Does this mean that it is off/inhibited unless pulled high externally? If thats the case how should I pull it high, do I need to use the 24V and a voltage divider?

Datasheet here: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLE7469-DS-v01_60-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46259d9a4bf0159f9e958903f04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the internal pull-down keeps the regulator off by default.

You can use the schematic example in the data sheet how to turn it on with a simple series resistor. A voltage divider will also be fine. It will turn on a bit above 3V, which is stated in the data sheet.

Comment: I don't really follow how an ignition key would pull it high.. I also don't really have another method to turn it on other than the 24V, as all of the circuitry on this board is powered by 3.3V & 5V...

Comment: The ignition key is likely just a switch that likely connects Vbat to the INH pin. Just use a 100k resistor and connect it to your 24V.

Comment: Good point, i just looked and saw that the Vmax on the INH pin is 45V. Thanks for the help!